# Conditional link to a file

Tags: hyperref, links

I have a pdf along with a "TheCDF" folder with some .cdf files (Wolfram CDF) that I want to share. In the pdf there are links to these .cdf files. I did it with the code

```
\newcommand{\myhref}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{./TheCDF/#1}{%
  \href{./CSCDF/#1}{If .cdf is in HD}
  }{%
\href{https://myweb/TheCDF/#1}{If no .cdf i HD} 
}
```

But... I want to create a link in the pdf in such a way that if the file is not in HD "TheCDF" folder (It could be lost), then it connects to the internet, to a specific address, to get the file. That can be done?

**Edit:**

Ok, suppose someone takes the pdf but forgets to take the folder "TheCDF" for some reason, then what I wanted is a link that first check the HD and, not finding the folder (or some file), then get it Internet automatically...

Comment: A PDF file is mostly static. If you create the PDF when the file is there, transferring it to another machine won't change the link and the file would not be found if not transferred as well. You probably need some JavaScript trickery.

Comment: I figured something like that

Comment: if you use javascript it won't work at all in most pdf readers, I would just link to the http version or use a file attachment and embed the cdf files inside the pdf.